# Jquery DatePicker show past dates

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

I am using the Jquery Datepicker found [here](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/index.html).
Does anyone know how I can modify this code to allow for past date selecting.

```
$('#start-date').bind('dpClosed', function(e, selectedDates) {
    var d = selectedDates[0];
    if (d) {
   d = new Date(d);
   $('#end-date').dpSetStartDate(d.addDays(1).asString()).dpSetSelected(d.asString()).val($(this).val());
  }
 });
```

Adding a

`$('.date-picker').dpSetStartDate('01/01/2000')`;

doesn't work. :(

I would greatly appreciate all help.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want dates in the past to be selectable it is as simple as:

```
$('.date-picker').datePicker({startDate:'01/01/2000'});
```

(see http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerPastDate.html )

Note that the startDate you pass in must me in the same format as you have set `Date.format` to (or dd/mm/yyyy by default).

You can also dynamically allow e.g. dates in the last year like so:

```
$('.date-picker'.datePicker({startDate: (new Date()).addYears(-1).asString()});
```

Comment: Hey vitch.

Thanks for that. I knew about 'startDate' but forgot I had changed the date format. Changing the date to my format fixed it.

Thanks again. Great Answer!

Tim

Answer (score 2):

you can use min date option also if you don't want to show the date before any specify date  as :-

$('#start-date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date());

// new Date will show today's date you can put any specific date a